# Sampling pandas DF to match a second DF within error

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have two DFs, say `df1,df2` as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,100],[1,1.1,120],[2,0.8,102]],columns=['id','a','b'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[0,0.5,110],[1,1.05,94],[2,0.96,145],[3,0.86,112],[4,1.3,97]],
                    columns=['id','a','b'])

print(df1)
   id    a    b
0   0  1.0  100
1   1  1.1  120
2   2  0.8  102
print(df2)
   id     a    b
0   0  0.50  110
1   1  1.05   94
2   2  0.96  145
3   3  0.86  112
4   4  1.30   97
```

Now, suppose I choose some interval size `da,db`. I want, for each row in `df1`, to pick a random row from `df2`, such that `abs(a1-a2)<da,abs(b1-b2)<db`. What I am currently doing is very brute force:

```
da = 0.2
db = 25
df2_list=[]
nbad = 0
for rid,row in df1.iterrows():
    ca = row['a']
    cb = row['b']
    c_df2 = df2[np.abs(df2['a']-ca)<da]\
            [np.abs(df2['b']-cb)<db]
    if len(c_df2) == 0:
        nbad+=1
        continue
    c_df2 = c_df2.sample()
    df2_list.append(c_df2['id'].values[0])

    
matched_df = df2[df2['id'].isin(df2_list)]
print(matched_df)

   id     a    b
1   1  1.05   94
3   3  0.86  112
4   4  1.30   97
```

However, for my real purpose, where my DF is really big, this is very slow.
Is there a faster way to achieve this result?

Comment: what are a1, a2, b1, b2 and db?

Comment: @Roy2012 These are just to illustrate the condition I want to impose. What I meant is that `a1` is a given value of `a` from a certain row in `df1`, and `a2` is any value of `a` from a row in `df2`. I want to pick a row in `df2`, call it `r`, such that `a1,r['a']` and `b1, r['b']` are close enough. I think the code snippet below it should explain it better.

Comment: how big are the two dataframes?

Comment: @Roy2012 A few tens of thousands rows

Comment: See my answer below. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
da = 0.2
db = 25

res = pd.merge(df1.assign(dummy = 1), df2.assign(dummy = 1), on = "dummy").drop("dummy", axis = 1)
res = res[(np.abs(res.a_x - res.a_y) < da) & (np.abs(res.b_x - res.b_y) < db)]
res = res.groupby("id_x").apply(lambda x: x.sample(1))[["id_y", "a_y", "b_y"]]
res.index = res.index.droplevel(1)
print(res)
```

The output is:

```
      id_y   a_y  b_y
id_x                 
0        1  1.05   94
1        4  1.30   97
2        3  0.86  112
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is slower than what I use now (using ipython timing, with 7 runs and 100 loops) by 60%

Comment: On the full data or on the sample data of a few lines?

Comment: I get that. I mean - did you compare with the real dataframes (thousands of rows) or wit the small example you posted here?

Comment: With the example posted here

Comment: I would try with a larger sample. You might see different results (doesn't mean that my code will perform better).